# How do I tab through search results in Safari?

Tags: safari, google-search

In Chrome, after a Google search, it is possible to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the search results. Then you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select and open that link.

Is possible to do the same on Safari 6?
After I searched something in the "omnibar", pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not on cycle search results, and instead passed focus through many other elements.
How do I get <kbd>Tab</kbd> to act like it does in Chrome?

Comment: Looks like this is not possible yet:  

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/is-there-an-option-shortcut-in-safari-6-to-focus-the-search-results-after-a-sear

Comment: You can use google's own shortcuts AFAIK...check this out....especially the experiment stuff... http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/navigate-google-search-results-keyboard/

If you could bring focus to search query box, you can use google instant shortcuts as well..

Answer (score 3):

Safari => preferences => advanced => Check Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage.

Love this in chrome myself. It still works a tiny bit better there, but checking that option makes it workable in safari.

Comment: but in this way only the first link is selected. after that, the focus goes everywhere again

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this with `Option + Tab`. Works for me on Safari in 2021